# std::initializer_list constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, object-construction, stdinitializerlist

In code like this:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <initializer_list>
#include <string>

struct A 
{
  A() { std::cout << "2" << std::endl; }
  A(int a) { std::cout << "0" << std::endl; }
  A(std::initializer_list<std::string> s) { std::cout << "3" << std::endl; }
  A(std::initializer_list<int> l) { std::cout << "1" << std::endl; } 
};

int main() 
{ 
 A a1{{}}; 
}
```

Why does it call `std::initializer_list<int>` specification of constructor?
It'll generate ambiguity compilation error if we define, for example, constructor with `std::initializer_list<double>`. What are the rules of such construction and why is it so specific about `std::initializer_list` with number as template argument?

Comment: Rolled back to previous version. @cse, you can't completely change after answers were posted...

Comment: @Barry now one answer addresses the first version, and another addresses the second version (full disclosure: it's mine). In that state of affairs, it might have been better to insert a bold note that states "Edit:" or something similar. I wasn't even aware of the edit and neither will future users be aware of the rollback unless they read the comments. **Edit:** Just noticed it wasn't the original author who edited the question. Not sure.. but perhaps the rollback was appropriate then.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If a class has an initializer list constructor, then `{whatever goes here}` means to pass `{whatevergoeshere}` as argument to the present constructors (if there are no initializer list constructors, then `whatever goes here` are passed as arguments).

So let's simplify the setting and ignore the other constructors, because apparently the compilers don't care about them

```
void f(std::initializer_list<std::string> s);
void f(std::initializer_list<int> l);
```

For `f({{}})` we have this rule

> Otherwise, if the parameter type is std​::​initializer_­list and all the elements of the initializer list can be implicitly converted to X, the implicit conversion sequence is the worst conversion necessary to convert an element of the list to X, or if the initializer list has no elements, the identity conversion. This conversion can be a user-defined conversion even in the context of a call to an initializer-list constructor.

Here we have a single element `{}` and it needs a user defined conversion to initialize `std::string` and no conversion (identity) for `int`. Therefore, `int` is chosen.

For `f({{{}}})` the element is `{{}}`. Can it be converted to `int`? The rule is

> - if the initializer list has one element that is not itself an initializer list, the implicit conversion sequence is the one required to convert the element to the parameter type
> - ...
> - In all cases other than those enumerated above, no conversion is possible.

Can it be converted to `std::string`? Yes, because it has an initializer list constructor that has a `std::initializer_list<char> init` parameter. Therefore, `std::string` is chosen this time.

---

The difference to `A a3({})` is that in such a case, it's not list initialization, but a "normal" initialization with a `{}` argument (note that one less nesting because of the missing outer braces). Here our two `f`-functions are called with `{}`. And since both lists have no elements, for both we have identity conversions and therefore an ambiguity.

The compiler in this case will also consider `f(int)` and get a tie with the other two functions. But a tie-breaker would apply that declares the `int` -parameter worse than the `initializer_list` parameters. So you have a partial order `{int} < {initializer_list<string>, initializer_list<int>}`, which is the reason for ambiguity, as the best group of conversion sequences does not contain a single candidate, but two.

Answer (score 8):

`{}` to a scalar type (such as `int`, `double`, `char*`, etc.) is the identity conversion.

`{}` to a class type other than a specialization of `std::initializer_list` (e.g., `std::string`) is a user-defined conversion.

The former beats the latter.

Comment: But why `A a1({});` is ambiguous then? I'm trying to find differences between _direct-initialization_ and _direct-list-initialization_ that matter here, but haven't succeeded yet.

Comment: @DanielLangr i edited my answer to explain the difference.