# How do I make a constructor take unlimited arguments in c++?

Tags: c++, list, class, overloading, instance

I am reimplementing `std::list` for educational purposes.

I was wondering if there was a way to allow the user to use this syntax for initialization:

```
my::list l = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

Comment: You can create a class that holds a list of configurations and methods that add to this configurations.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization

Comment: possible dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48496848/stdinitializer-list-constructor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what initializer lists are for.
You could for example have a constructor like this:

```
class list {
public:
    list(std::initializer_list<int> l) {
        for (int x : l) {
            // do something with x
        }
    }
};
```

Or making it more generic by using templates:

```
template<typename T>
class list {
public:
    list(std::initializer_list<T> l) {
        for (const auto &x : l) {
            // do something with x
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Good effort :).

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution using variadic templates:

```
template<typename T>
class my::list {
public:
    template<typename... Args>
    list(Args... args) { init(args...); }
    void push_back(T);
private:
    template<typename... Args>
    void init(T value, Args... args) {
        push_back(value);
        init(args...);
    }
};
```

the `init` function calls itself recursively, and it checks that the first value is of type `T`, then pushes it inside the list.